# SSRS - Reference a Textbox Value from a RowGroup

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have a tablix that is using RowGroups to group instances of data. A textbox in the tablix refers to a field as it relates to everything else in that group of data. I would like to create a textbox outside the group, below the tablix, and have it reference the value of that textbox inside the group. I have attempted referencing the group textbox using *=ReportItems!GroupTextbox1.Value* but this returns empty.  Is this in anyway possible in SSRS? Thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: Where you are referencing the group value after the group prints or after a series of groups print? There are a few options. You may be able to use a calculated field in the dataset or a Code global variable. The report item route may repeat many times and I do not know if it would be reliable to reference it out of scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This scenario is probably not supported, ref http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx

If you provided some more info on what output you are trying to achieve (not just your code) we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone:
You can use Custom code-feature of the report. Open the Report properties and then Code-tab. In there you can write or own code to save results and read them later on. The variables are in report-scope.  Like:

```
Public Shared Dim MyValue as Double = 0
Public Function SaveMyValue (ByVal s As Double) as Double
   MyValue+=s
   Return s
End Function

Public Function GetMyValue() as  Double
  Return MyValue 
End Function
```

And using these functions goes like this, eg. in Textbox expression:
=Code.SaveMyValue(Fields!SomeValue.Value)