# In SSRS how to I access the contents of one text box (in a grid) elsewhere in the report?

Tags: reporting-services, field, output

I've created a grid - based on its own data set. 
I've calculated the grand total of a column by summing all the output. 
I now need to access that text box/element (which I named grandtotal). 
I have a new text box at the bottom of the report - in that field I want to display (once more) the grandtotal I can't seem to find good instructions for doing this.

Comment: Have you tried ReportItems!grandtotal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope that's not possible. Only fields/parameters/constants/calculated expressions can be evaluated. The sum totals is calculated internally by SSRS engine which can't be accessed. Do the calculation(summation) in a dataset and use it instead. See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298612/ssrs-reference-a-textbox-value-from-a-rowgroup).

Comment: There is no way to say - Textbox30 (or Grandtotal since i've renamed it). and simply to access that data - even if its on the fly.

Comment: Exactly that's what I am saying. You need to do the summation inside a dataset and then pull it elsewhere.

Comment: That seems to duplicate the work - but since that is the only option I will do so. Thank you.